# Why does 'lock_type' of information_schema.INNODB_LOCKS always RECORD?

Tags: mysql, innodb

According to the doc: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locks-table.html,

> LOCK_TYPE of INFORMATION_SCHEMA INNODB_LOCKS Table should have 2
>   possible values: RECORD AND TABLE.

However, I haven't seen that field to be "TABLE". Whatever I tried, it has always been "RECORD". Is there anyone could offer me a case to make the "TABLE" happen?

Thanks,
Xianyi Ye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You link to some MySQL 5.7 documentation, so I assume you're using 5.7.

The only table locks in InnoDB are *metadata locks* which are also called *intention locks*, documented here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-intention-locks

Any transaction that wants to do some DML operation to read or write records in a table (i.e. SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) needs to acquire a metadata lock first. Multiple concurrent sessions can acquire metadata locks to do DML, and these don't conflict with each other.

Likewise, metadata operations (DDL statements ALTER, DROP, or TRUNCATE TABLE) need to acquire a metadata lock before they can begin. Thus the DDL statements are blocked if there are any transactions running DML statements, and vice-versa.

This is how DML is blocked from querying a table during a long-running ALTER.

In MySQL 5.7, you can set up some PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA instruments for metadata locks, but it's a fair bit of work. See https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/12/28/quickly-troubleshooting-metadata-locks-mysql-5-7/

In MySQL 8.0.1, there's a new [PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA.DATA_LOCKS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-locks-table.html) by default to monitor these locks. Here's an example:

```
mysql> select * from performance_schema.data_locks\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               ENGINE: INNODB
       ENGINE_LOCK_ID: 4874033848:1112:140194859105464
ENGINE_TRANSACTION_ID: 15171
            THREAD_ID: 49
             EVENT_ID: 12
        OBJECT_SCHEMA: test
          OBJECT_NAME: mytable
       PARTITION_NAME: NULL
    SUBPARTITION_NAME: NULL
           INDEX_NAME: NULL
OBJECT_INSTANCE_BEGIN: 140194859105464
            LOCK_TYPE: TABLE                <-- TABLE lock
            LOCK_MODE: IX                   <-- "IX" intention lock mode
          LOCK_STATUS: GRANTED
            LOCK_DATA: NULL
*************************** 2. row ***************************
               ENGINE: INNODB
       ENGINE_LOCK_ID: 4874033848:55:4:2:140194863232024
ENGINE_TRANSACTION_ID: 15171
            THREAD_ID: 49
             EVENT_ID: 12
        OBJECT_SCHEMA: test
          OBJECT_NAME: mytable
       PARTITION_NAME: NULL
    SUBPARTITION_NAME: NULL
           INDEX_NAME: PRIMARY
OBJECT_INSTANCE_BEGIN: 140194863232024
            LOCK_TYPE: RECORD
            LOCK_MODE: X
          LOCK_STATUS: WAITING
            LOCK_DATA: 1
```

There's also a [METADATA_LOCKS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/metadata-locks-table.html) table:

```
mysql> select * from performance_schema.metadata_locks;
+-------------+--------------------+----------------+-------------+-----------------------+---------------------+---------------+-------------+-------------------+-----------------+----------------+
| OBJECT_TYPE | OBJECT_SCHEMA      | OBJECT_NAME    | COLUMN_NAME | OBJECT_INSTANCE_BEGIN | LOCK_TYPE           | LOCK_DURATION | LOCK_STATUS | SOURCE            | OWNER_THREAD_ID | OWNER_EVENT_ID |
+-------------+--------------------+----------------+-------------+-----------------------+---------------------+---------------+-------------+-------------------+-----------------+----------------+
| TABLE       | test               | mytable        | NULL        |       140194860588144 | SHARED_WRITE        | TRANSACTION   | GRANTED     | sql_parse.cc:5820 |              48 |             26 |
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
what Mysql version are you using?

Mysql8 INFORMATION SCHEMA does not have the table INNODB_LOCKS
mysql> show tables like '%innodb%';
+-----------------------------------------+
| Tables_in_information_schema (%INNODB%) |
+-----------------------------------------+
| INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE                      |
| INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU                  |
| INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS                |
| INNODB_CACHED_INDEXES                   |
| INNODB_CMP                              |
| INNODB_CMPMEM                           |
| INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET                     |
| INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX                    |
| INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET              |
| INNODB_CMP_RESET                        |
| INNODB_COLUMNS                          |
| INNODB_DATAFILES                        |
| INNODB_FIELDS                           |
| INNODB_FOREIGN                          |
| INNODB_FOREIGN_COLS                     |
| INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED                 |
| INNODB_FT_CONFIG                        |
| INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD              |
| INNODB_FT_DELETED                       |
| INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE                   |
| INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE                   |
| INNODB_INDEXES                          |
| INNODB_METRICS                          |
| INNODB_TABLES                           |
| INNODB_TABLESPACES                      |
| INNODB_TABLESPACES_BRIEF                |
| INNODB_TABLESTATS                       |
| INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO                  |
| INNODB_TRX                              |
| INNODB_VIRTUAL                          |
+-----------------------------------------+
30 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

ref
http://drib.tech/programming/debug-monitor-mysql-locks